# Fragments, ListView and Custom Adapters

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I'm a newbie on android and I'm creating an application.
The application layout is configured with [Swipe Views](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). One of this fragments have a `ListView` with history of completed actions. When a user clicks on a button, the application pick some data and put then on a `ListView.` The layout inflated is a custom layout. But when I try to click on button the application stop working. See that:

**Adapter**

```
public class ChronoListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RegExpItem> {

    private ArrayList<RegExpItem> regExpItems = null;
    private Context context;

    public ChronoListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<RegExpItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Inflate Row and retrieve TextViews and ImageViews
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View listItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView regExpItem = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.RegExpList);
        TextView stringItem = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.StringList);
        ImageView matchItem = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.MatchList);

        //Insert Strings
        regExpItem.setText(regExpItems.get(position).regExp);
        stringItem.setText(regExpItems.get(position).strings);

        //Change image for true or false
        if (regExpItems.get(position).match) {
            matchItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checkmark_holo_light);
        } else {
            matchItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear_search_api_holo_light);
        }
        return listItem;
    }
}
```

**Implementation on ChronoFragment (onCreateView())**

**OnClick**

```
RegExpItem rei = new RegExpItem(regExp, input, true);
regExpItems.add(rei);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Eclipse doesn't give any problems and I don't have build problems. How can I resolve that?

PS: the `ArrayList` is empty when I assign that to my Adapter.

EDIT: After some tries, I think that application crash when I add item to `ArrayList`

**Stacktrace**

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 572  
Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) line: 532  
Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() line: 735 
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 730   
Choreographer$FrameHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92   
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5289    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 739  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 555 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

**Logcat**

```
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188): at com.slinky.regexptool.ChronoListAdapter.getView(ChronoListAdapter.java:30)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:736)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1655)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1589)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14296)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
11-08 11:06:38.360: E/AndroidRuntime(10188):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeMethod)
```

Comment: Post a stacktrace if your application crashed

Comment: Would you please post a more meaningful logcat output, because this one neither contains ChronoFragment nor ChronoListAdapter classes.

Comment: Posted changelog filtered for my package with warn level

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this to the constructor of your ChronoListAdapter:

```
this.regExpItems = objects;
```

If this is the problem then your application crashes on a NullPointerException. You can see the stacktraces for Android in Eclipse with LogCat (Window -> Show view -> Other... -> LogCat.

Comment: This isn't the problem. The application crash on a NPE 'Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))' How i can fix that?

Comment: Then where does regExpItems get populated?

Comment: It's populated when user click on button. But one item every click